# Move Last Four Lines To Second Row In Text File

Tags: linux, unix, sed, tail

I need to move the last 4 lines of a text file and move them to the second row in the text file.

I'm assuming that tail and sed are used but, I haven't much luck so far.

Comment: Please show your efforts; also an example of the input & output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `head` and `tail` solution.  Let us start with the same sample file as Glenn Jackman:

```
$ seq 10 >file
```

Apply these commands:

```
$ head -n1 file ; tail -n4 file; tail -n+2 file | head -n-4
1
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
```

Explanation:

- `head -n1 file`

  Print first line
- `tail -n4 file`

  Print last four lines
- `tail -n+2 file | head -n-4`

  Print the lines starting with line 2 and ending before the fourth-to-last line.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm assuming correctly, `ed` can handle your task:

```
seq 10 > file

ed file <<'COMMANDS'
$-3,$m1
w
q
COMMANDS

cat file
```

```
1
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
```

lines 7,8,9,10 have been moved to the 2nd line

`$-3,$m1` means, for the range of lines from "$-3" (3 lines before the last line) to "$" (the last line, move them ("m") below the first line ("1")

Note that the heredoc has been quoted so the shell does not try to interpret the strings `$-` and `$m1` as variables

If you don't want to actually modify the file, but instead print to stdout:

```
ed -s file <<'COMMANDS'
$-3,$m1
%p
Q
COMMANDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
seq 10 > file
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR-4;i++) if (i==2) {for (j=NR-3;j<=NR;j++) print a[j];print a[i]} else print a[i]}' file
1
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
```